# PhpStorm + Docker + Xdebug + DB SSH tunnel

Tags: php, docker, phpstorm, xdebug, ssh-tunnel

Locally I have following docker-compose configuration:

```
nginx:
  build:
    context: ./nginx
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  volumes:
    - ./../logs:/home/web/logs/
    - ./../:/home/web/my-website.com/
  depends_on:
    - php
php:
  build:
    context: ./php
  volumes:
    - ./../:/home/web/my-website.com/
  working_dir: /home/web/my-website.com/
  expose:
    - "8123"
```

`php` container has Xdebug installed into it, I can easily connect to it from PhpStorm.

I have remote ClickHouse database which is connected via SSH Tunnel. When I start my container I just go into my container and execute:

```
ssh -4 login@host.com -p 2211 -L 8123:localhost:8123 -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -Nf
```

After this, my site is able to use this connection, but when I execute console command

```
./yii analysis/start-charts 003b56fe-db47-11e8-bcc0-52540010e5bc 205
```

from PhpStorm, I'm getting an exception:

```
Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8123: Connection refused
```

If I jump into the container and launch the same command, everything works fine.

What's wrong? Why PhpStorm doesn't see my SSH tunnel?

Comment: Running it in PhpStorm equals running it using your machine's terminal: the command isn't run inside of a container. I would assume that running `./yii analysis/start-charts 003b56fe-db47-11e8-bcc0-52540010e5bc 205` in a console of your workstation would also fail? Btw, are you running this command simply in Terminal or you're doing Tools > Start SSH Session... > etc?

Comment: @Ástþór, as far as I know, PhpStorm uses an interpreter, which I set in project settings. In my case, it uses interpreter from docker container, on my workstation no PHP installed. According to your second question, firstly I execute command `docker exec -u www-data -it docker_php_1 /bin/bash` and only then I execute command `./yii analysis/start-charts ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got an answer on "superuser" site: https://superuser.com/questions/1374463/phpstorm-docker-xdebug-db-ssh-tunnel/1375961#1375961

Besides, I've added `ports` node to my `php` container definition, now it's the following:

```
  php:
    build:
      context: ./php
    volumes:
      - ./../:/home/web/my-website.com/
    working_dir: /home/web/my-website.com/
    expose:
      - "8123"
    ports:
      - "8123:8123"
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - mysql
```